# Changing the column of the current working cell.coordinate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to change the column of a cell.coordinate to the next column and was wondering how can you do as such? For instance, I'm currently working in cell A5  or  any A# to change it to cell B5 or  any B#.

Background:

I am working on a program that globs a directory from a two column xlsx file. The first column is the file names and the second column is the particular text I want to search. The program uses the file names of the first column, prints if it finds a match, but for so reason haven't been able to come up with way to change the current working cell to the next column over A# to B# and use that string in B# to search a doc. ( I was able to figure out how search a doc but if I force a string a but just trying to figure how to do that with a xlsx document)

Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Please include any code that you have so far tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the [tutorial](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html), you need to call the `iter_rows` method on an instance of a worksheet, for example:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows('A:B'):
    for cell in row:
        print cell
```

If the first column is the *filename* and the second is the *text*, you can try:

```
for row in ws.iter_rows('A:B'):
    filename_cell, text_cell = row
    filename = filename_cell.value
    text = text_cell.value
    my_search(filename, text)
```

Where `my_search()` is your function used to search a text in a file…